# Publishing videos on TikTok using TikTok API?

Tags: tiktok-api

This has been a big mystery to me so I'm gonna ask here in a hope that someone can help me with it.

So, I'm trying to use the TikTok API to `Auto Publish` videos onto TikTok's account.

I cannot find any information about this on their API docs.

So I did a research and found out that other companies like 'Later' or 'HootSuit' have this Auto Publishing feature for TikTok.

So I signed up on Later to test how they do it. I found out that there are these Scopes/Permissions being used:

```
user.info.basic,
user.insights,
video.list,
video.insights,
comment.list,
comment.list.manage,
video.publish
```

and I found those from the URL when I allowed the Later TikTok App to be added to my TikTok account:

```
https://www.tiktok.com/auth/authorize?client_id=7051484449883553794&client_key=7051484449883553794&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.later.com%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ftiktok_business%2Fcallback%3Fstate%3De0af91a683a02ec0636ee1b42e6e9caf60ccc8295252260b&response_type=code&scope=user.info.basic%2Cuser.insights%2Cvideo.list%2Cvideo.insights%2Ccomment.list%2Ccomment.list.manage%2Cvideo.publish&state=e0af91a683a02ec0636ee1b42e6e9caf60ccc8295252260b
```

My TikTok app (this is the API app), asks for these permissions:

```
user.info.basic,
video.upload,
```

Now, I know that is the fist and most probably the main issue here BUT I don't have any option to add those Scopes to my App!

The only scopes that TikTok API mentions and talks about are these:

```
user.info.basic
video.list
video.upload
```

which you can see here:

https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/tiktok-api-scopes/

My app now only uploads the video on the users account and the users get a push notification on their app asking them to login to their account and edit/pulish the video!

So there is no auto publishing.

Just to clarify, the user's account is a business account as well as this is a requirement for the TikTok auto publishing to work.

The question is, where and how I can add those scopes/permissions to my App?

are there any other steps that I need to take?

Comment: Hello Drago, 

Even if it has nothing to do with your initial question, I would like to ask you the following question

Were you able to get a valid URL with multiple scopes? My application has the video.list scope but when I try to add it to the user.basic.info, TikTok tells me that my scope is wrong. (works well with only user.basic.info)

URL: https://www.tiktok.com/auth/authorize?client_key=my_key&response_type=code&redirect_uri=my_url&scope=user.info.basic%2Cvideo.list&state=my_state

Comment: @thomasA, Yes, I don't have any issues with getting a valid url with multiple scopes. use this instead: 
https://www.tiktok.com/auth/authorize?client_key=YOUR-KEY&scope=user.info.basic,video.upload,video.list&response_type=code&redirect_uri=your-redirect-rul%3Fstate%3D6356cdb2d12a1&state=6356cdb2d12a1

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a Tiktok Business account, may you should rather use the Marketing APi (https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1753986142651394)

This has video publish scopes too and is a lot different from the Tiktok API you get from Tiktok for developers.

**Note:**
Tiktok for developers API is geared towards general use, while the Marketing API is for Businesses, hence more features.

**Caution**
JFYI, If you have a business account, you cannot monetize the content. I am facing the same issue, but i cant move to business account(and Marketing API) for that reason.

Comment: Also, if you were able to figure out another way to get it to publish without having a business account and using Tiktok API. Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to add scops in your developer account like 'video.publish','user.info.basic'.
and submit for review I think they will approve your app scops changes in 24 hours. then you need to use direct publish API for direct publish your video
which is 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/'

but you need to follow tiktok guideline https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/content-posting-api-get-started/ for direct publish

first of all need to call creator/info API for getting account info then you can use direct publish apis

here there are two option for uploading video "FILE_UPLOAD" and "PULL_FROM_URL". if you have your videos uploaded on third party video storage so you can directly use that Video URL to direct post using "PULL_FROM_URL" method but in this case you need to verify your video domain or if you have direct video then you can use "FILE_UPLOAD" method

there is some detail documentation and guideline for video upload you can find it here https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/content-posting-api-media-transfer-guide/ this full guideline for video upload using chunk and video upload using url

Comment: They reject my submission because I didn't implement video publish for ALL users. I just did local server solution, for my account, and this will not pass approval

Answer (score 0):

In case you will pass approval, you can use this code as an example:

```js
    export const postStory = async (story) => {
        try {
            const content = fs.readFileSync(TOKEN_PATH);
            const token = JSON.parse(content);
            let options = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token.data.access_token,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                },
            };
    
            let response = await fetch("https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/creator_info/query/", options);
            let data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
    
            const body = {
                post_info: {
                    title: "#manga " + story.description.substring(0, 50).replaceAll("<", "").replaceAll(">", ""),
                    privacy_level: "PUBLIC_TO_EVERYONE",
                    disable_duet: false,
                    disable_comment: false,
                    disable_stitch: false,
                    video_cover_timestamp_ms: 2000,
                },
                source_info: {
                    source: "PULL_FROM_URL",
                    video_url: API + story.video,
                },
            };
            console.log(body);
            options = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token.data.access_token,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            };
    
            response = await fetch("https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/", options);
            data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
```